# Pytest init setup for few modules

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Say i have next tests structure:

```
test/
  module1/   
    test1.py
  module2/
    test2.py
  module3/
    test3.py
```

How can i setup some method to be called only once before all this tests?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use autouse fixtures:

```
# content of test/conftest.py 

import pytest
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def execute_before_any_test():
    # your setup code goes here, executed ahead of first test
```

See [pytest fixture docs](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html) for more info.

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize that being in a `conftest.py` is a key point to the 'globalness' of this solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note: to make use of variables created in `conftest.py` module execute inside testcase `import conftest`, and later in testcase refer to a variable `foo` declared in conftest as `conftest.foo`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean only once in each run of the test suit, then setup and teardown are what you are looking for.

```
def setup_module(module):
    print ("This will at start of module")

def teardown_module(module):
    print ("This will run at end of module")
```

Similarly  you can have *setup_function* and *teardown_function* which will run at start and end of each test function repetitively. You can also add *setup* and *teardown* member function in test classes to run at start and end of the test class run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django and trying to create database objects using [hpk42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20057171/7560156), it will fail with this error:

> RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it

In this situation, pytest offers an example piece of code to work around this:

```py
import pytest

from myapp.models import Widget

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def django_db_setup(django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    with django_db_blocker.unblock():
        Widget.objects.create(...)
```

Documentation is here: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#populate-the-test-database-if-you-use-transactional-or-live-server